# Texture binding on UV stretches texture if aspect ratio not 1:1

Tags: uv, distort

I'm rather new to blender and still learning a lot every day.
I stumbled upon a behaviour of blender that I don't really understand, nor can I find a way to fix it. I've UV-Unwrapped a model of a mousepad and I'm putting an image texture on it's up facing side. Everytime I do this, the texture ends up being distorted.

I don't have any stretching on my UV and I applied all the scaling. The material I use for the texture is only applied to the top side and I do use the proper node setup for binding an image texture to a UV-Map.

Texture always ends up distorted, if it's not a ratio of 1:1.
Is there a way to fix this? Or is this some sort of default behaviour, one just has to work with?

I'll add images to show what I mean, with the original image for comparison and a UV-Grid to see the stretching.

[image: Viewport]

[image: Node Setup]

Comment: create the material and then unwrap it again. If there is no Image texture yet, it creates a square UV Map.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it.
The comment from Timmethy did help quite a bit, but in my opinion Blender does behave very odd.

The UV behaved as if it was on a square plane and using it with an image texture that was not square would lead to distortion.
For some reason selecting an image with the same ratio as the texture (or the texture itself) in the image data block and unwrapping it again fixed it. But not that easily. Just selecting the whole thing and unwrapping it didn't change anything. What worked was selecting and unwrapping a single face first, before selecting and unwrapping the whole mesh.

I don't really know. This behaviour is confusing and somewhat nonsensical and I didn't realize that selecting an image in the UV-Image-Editor would actually affect UV during the unwrapping. But just unwrapping it again with a different image selected doesn't do anything either.

In any case.
It's fixed and I'm just somewhat frustrated.

Thanks for the help.